# CoreldrawVBA Select multiple Objects by Name

Tags: vba, selection, coreldraw

Guys I am new to VBA for Coreldraw and am searching for some help in selecting multiple objects by name

I have two objects 1 is a curve and one is a rectangle. I name them OBJ1 & OBJ 2 with the following Code

```
For Each s In sr.Shapes
    objName = s.Name
    objName = "OBJ1"
    If objName <> "" Then
    s.Name = objName
    End If
    Next s
For Each s In sr.Shapes
    objName = s.Name
    objName = "OBJ2"
    If objName <> "" Then
    s.Name = objName
    End If
    Next s
```

I Then have tried the following code to select the two objects which I need to do so I can then perform a trim

```
    Dim s as Shape
    ActiveDocument.ClearSelection
    Set s = ActivePage.FindShape(Name:="OBJ1")
    ActivePage.FindShape(Name:="OBJ2").AddToSelection
    s.CreateSelection
```

Problem is the result is that only OBJ1 is selected OBJ2 remains UN-selected

I'm sure its something stupid but would appreciate any help you could give

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

    CreateSelectionByNames Array("OBJ1", "OBJ2")

End Sub


Sub CreateSelectionByNames(aNames)

    Dim sName
    Dim shpRange As New ShapeRange

    For Each sName In aNames
        shpRange.Add ActivePage.FindShape(Name:=sName)
    Next
    shpRange.CreateSelection

End Sub
```